# JAX-WS Webservice with JPA transactions

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic12c

I'm going to become mad with JPA...

I have a JAX-WS Webservice like that

```
@WebService
public class MyService
{
    @EJB private MyDbService myDbService;

    ...
    System.out.println(dmrService.read());
    ...
}
```

My EJB contains

```
@Stateless
public class MyDbService
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="mypu")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public MyEntity read()
    {
    MyEntity myEntity;

    String queryString = "SELECT ... WHERE e.name = :type";

    TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString,MyEntity.class);
    query.setParameter("type","xyz");

    try
    {
        myEntity= query.getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        myEntity= null;
    }

    return myEntity;
}
```

In my `persistence.xml` the `mypu` has `transaction-type="JTA"` and a `jta-data-source`

If I call the webservice, it's working.  The entity is retrieved from the db.

Now, using an external tool, I'm changing the value of one field in my record.

I'm calling the webservice again and ... the entity displayed contains the old value.

If I'm deploying again, or if I'm adding a entityManager.refresh(myEntity) after the request, I have the good value again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In @MyTwoCents [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52645663/496099), Option 2 is to NOT use your 'external' tool for changes, use your application instead. Caching is of more use if your application knows about all the changes going on, or has some way of being informed of them. This is the better option, but only if your application can be the single access point for the data.

Forcing a refresh, via EntityManager.refresh() or through [provider specific query hints](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints#Refresh) on specific queries, or by invalidating the cache as described here https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching#How_to_refresh_the_cache is another option. This forces JPA to go past the cache and access the database on the specific query. Problems with this are you must either know when the cache is stale and needs to be refreshed, or put it on queries that cannot tolerate stale data. If that is fairly frequent or on every query, then your application is going through all the work of maintaining a cache that isn't used.

The last option is to [turn off the second level cache](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching). This forces queries to always load entities into an EntityManager from the database data, not a second level cache. You reduce the risk of stale data (but not eliminate it, as the EntityManager is required to have its own first level cache for managed entities, representing a transactional cache), but at the cost of reloading and rebuilding entities, sometimes unnecessarily if they have been read before by other threads.

Which is best depends entirely on the application and its expected use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be mad its fine

Flow goes like this.

- You fired a query saying where type="xyz"
- Now Hibernate keeps this query or state in cache so that if you fire query again it will return same value if state is not changes.
- Now you are updating detail from some external resource.
- Hibernate doesnt have any clue about that
- So when you fire query again it returns from catch
- When you do refresh, hibernate gets detail from Database

Solution :

1. So you can either add refresh before calling get call

OR

2. Change the Table value using Hibernate methods in Application so that Hibernate is aware about changes.

OR

3. Disable Hibernate cache to query each time from DB (not recommended as it will slow down stuff)

Comment: Thanks MyTwoCents.  So it is the normal behavior.  What to you mean by 'before calling get call' ?  Adding entityManager.refresh(myEntity); just before the return myEntity ?  Can you develop a little more your solution 2 ?  What's the best between 1 et 2 ?